# My loop over days is very long

Tags: kotlin

I've the below `data structure`, which is including the transaction date and quantity, as will as `day stamp` in millisecods

```
data class transaction (var date: LocalDate, var quantity: Double) {

    private var calendar: Calendar =
            GregorianCalendar(date.year, (date.monthValue + 1), date.dayOfMonth)

    var day_stamp: Long = calendar.timeInMillis
}
```

The above is used to define 2 arrays of variables:

```
var salesOrders = ArrayList<transaction>()
var demand = ArrayList<transaction>()
```

The `sales Orders` array, is created by:

```
val formatter: DateTimeFormatter
    get() = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.mm.yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)

salesOrders.add(transaction(LocalDate.parse("01.02.2018", formatter), 100.0))
salesOrders.add(transaction(LocalDate.parse("01.02.2018", formatter), 80.0))
salesOrders.add(transaction(LocalDate.parse("02.02.2018", formatter), 120.0))
salesOrders.add(transaction(LocalDate.parse("02.02.2018", formatter), 90.0))
```

As seen, we could have multiple sales orders required at the same day, and I need to put the sum of the quantities required each day in the `demand` array, which will be showing each day, and the total of sales orders quantities, to do so, I used the `day stamp` as reference `Considering a day is of: 24 hrs * 60 min/hour * 60,000 millisecond/min = 86,400,000 millisecond` and used the below code:

```
for (i in 1519862400000..1519862400000 step 86400000){

    var calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(i);

    val mYear: Int = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)

    val mMonth: Int = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)

    val mDay: Int = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    val acc = salesOrders.filter { it.day_stamp == i }.
            fold (0.0) {s, els -> s.plus(els.quantity) }

    demand.add(transaction(LocalDate.of(mDay, mMonth, mYear),acc))
}
```

I feel this loop will consume much more time than required, is there a better practice/way to do this, any better code? thanks.

Comment: Hmm, the current loop in your code simply iterates through one single element: `for (i in 1519862400000..1519862400000 step 86400000){
        println(i)
    }` will only print `1519862400000`. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: This is O(M *n). A much better strategy would be 1. to stop using Calendar and milliseconds (just use LocalDate directly. BTW, all days don't have the same number of milliseconds). 2. To just use a Map<LocalDate, Double>, containing, for each day, the sum of quantities for that day. If you really need the quantities for other days, then it's easy: it's 0, because it's not in the Map.

Comment: do not know the full context of the problem, but from the snippet, it seems like you need to group sales by day_stamp and simply sum each grouped list of sales

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do what you need:

```
val demand = salesOrders.groupingBy { it.date }.fold(0.0) { sum: Double, t: transaction ->
    sum + t.quantity
}.map { transaction(it.key, it.value) }
```

The input `salesOrders` will be grouped by date before all quantities are summed up and again mapped to new `transaction` instances.

Please note that your formatter is not working as intended: Change to `"dd.MM.yyyy"`.

Comment: Nice solution with the `groupingBy` method